# ListFeatureClasses overriding ListRasters in ArcMap script

Tags: arcpy

What is preventing the script from identifying the spatial reference for the .tif files?  It appears that the script below lists the fc first, then gives the false spatial reference to the subsequent .tif files in the list.  Similarly, if there's a fc with an undefined spatial reference, the .tif files show "unknown".

[image]
[image]

```
arcpy.env.workspace = in_workspace
feature_classes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in feature_classes:
    spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference
    if spatial_ref.name == "Unknown":
        arcpy.AddError("{0} has an unknown spatial reference".format(fc))
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage("{0} : {1}".format(fc, spatial_ref.name))
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
for raster in rasters:  
                arcpy.AddMessage("{0} : {1}".format(raster, spatial_ref.name))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't queried the raster(s) to get the spatial reference, the `spatial_ref` variable is still set to the spatial reference of the last feature class.

Instead of this:

```
for raster in rasters:  
    arcpy.AddMessage("{0} : {1}".format(raster, spatial_ref.name))
```

Do this:

```
for raster in rasters:  
    spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(raster).spatialReference
    arcpy.AddMessage("{0} : {1}".format(raster, spatial_ref.name))
```